# iOS - Shifting from UITextField to another doesn't start the Second One

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

Here is the UI:
I have a table view that has rows including text fields. For example row1 has textField1 and row2 has textField2.

Now, if the user taps the textField1, everything works fine. The delegate is called and everything.

If the user, then, taps the textField2, only the `textFieldDidEndEditing:` is called for textField1. `textFieldDidBeginEditing:` is not called for textField2 (I am pretty sure that textField2 delegate is set, because when I then tap textField2 (again), it starts editing (`textFieldDidBeginEditing:` is now called)

You may think this is not a real problem. The problem is that the iOS keeps showing the keyboard! With no text fields associated to it! I even loop to all text fields in all visible rows and resign them with no luck.

Seems a bug in iOS, right?

**Edit:** Here is the code in the delegate

```
   - (void) textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    [self fixTableViewOffsets];

    RSMCellEditPricesCell *cell = (RSMCellEditPricesCell *) [[textField superview] superview];
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell]
                          atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionTop
                                  animated:YES];

}

- (void) textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {

    self.currentPriceTextField = nil;
    [self fixTableViewOffsets];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: It's rely hard to find a problem without the code for textFieldDidBegin/EndEditing and the code from `cellForRow` method. Also are you listening for Keyboard notifications in your code ?

Comment: Added the delegate methods. I am not listening for Keyboard notifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a fix for it. However, as a workaround, I disabled the second text field. When the user taps this field, it will trigger the touch event on cell, not the text field which will dismiss the keyboard. Then, I enable all text fields and the user can select this second text field again.

It's not quite a solution and it doesn't provide the best UX. Still, it work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, be careful with the naming conventions, if you are adding a `label` at the end of a variable that variable should be a `UILabel` not a `UITextField`. Second your problem might be in the `textFieldDidEndEditing` method, you are calling `resignFirstResponder` on all your text fields(if the cell.priceLabel is a text field). You shouldn't call`resignFirstResponder` in `textFieldDidEndEditing` or `textFieldSouldReturn` because if those methods are called the text fields are already resign as first responder.

Comment: Well, I renamed the text field (I wrote as a draft and even then I was also wrong). I removed the resignFirstResponder, it was a try to hide the sticky keyboard - just to prove my point. Still, the bug exists. I think it's an iOS thing.

Comment: @A.Shatou Another thing that cross to my mind, did you added the textfields to the cell's containerView ? Because it's possible that your cell get's the touch event instead of your textField. You should try to add a textField directly to the cell (addSubview) and test it.

Comment: this is a custom cell created in nib, not by code (hence added to the content view). Also, even then, why the keyboard is kept shown?